# Detecting two-finger click on Siri remote

Tags: uikit, uigesturerecognizer, tvos, siri-remote

I'd like to detect when the user of my tvOS app clicks the Siri Remote with two fingers on the trackpad. (Currently, clicking with one finger increments; I'd like clicking with two fingers to decrement.) On iOS, detecting a two-finger tap is pretty easy: just attach a `UITapGestureRecognizer` with `numberOfTouchesRequired` set to `2`. But I can't seem to make this work on tvOS. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I tried looking in the official tvos documentation, but i can't confirm that it is "one-touch" or "multi-touch".

Though, from my current testing and exploration with the siri remote, it only supports one touch.